# Python Bisection method

Tags: python

I am pleased to get here, I apologize, I am a beginner coder, and am taking the MIT open course for self learning. I am doing the problem set:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/assignments/MIT6_0001F16_ps1.pdf

I am currently having problems at the problem C which implements the bisection method, and my code is as follows:

```
total_cost = 1000000
portion_down_payment = 0.25
current_savings = 0
semi_annual_raise = .07
r = 0.04
month = 0
savings_rate = 0 
down_payment = portion_down_payment*total_cost

annual_salary = float (input('Enter your annual salary: '))

low = 0.0
high = 10000
ans = (high+low)/2.0


while (down_payment - current_savings > 100):
    current_savings = current_savings + current_savings*(r/12) + (annual_salary/12)*(ans/100)       
    if (down_payment - current_savings > 100):
        high = ans
    else: 
        low = ans        
    ans = (high+low)/2.0

    if month%6 == 0:
            annual_salary = annual_salary + semi_annual_raise*annual_salary
    month+=1
    if month > 36:
        print ('down payment not possible in 3 years')
        break


print('savings rate:', ans/100) 
print('month', month)
```

Is there something I am missing, because the code keeps exiting at the first loop etc...I apologize for my stupidity, I am a beginner learner. I would like to learn and improve, thanks a million community.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you are asking about a homework / exercise. You should read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). I will try to give you some pointers without solving the exercise.

Step 1: Define what you are trying to achieve with the bisection. The problem asks, more or less "what is the saving rate (if any) that will achieve a `current_savings` within 100 of `down_payment` in 36 months". This can give you the pointer for the first bisection condition.

Something like:

```
while True:
    if abs(down_payment - current_savings) < 100:
        break
    elif down_payment > current_savings:
        low = ans
    else: 
        high = ans      
    ans = (high+low)//2   #note the integer division here
```

Step 2: sometimes, you just cannot achieve the saving even with 100% saving rate. you add something like:

```
if ans >= 9999:
    break
```

Now you need something that calculates `current_savings` at the end of 36 months. You can use a `for` loop, or a `function`, or both (I'll leave that to you).

Try to break the problem in steps and ask here if you don't understand / cannot solve one of these steps

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help, all i needed was pointers, and not for you to solve, so I can learn on my own. I will work on it further and if my solution works, will post. Thank you